# What is the relationship between bandwidth in the context of a passable range of frequencies vs bits per second being transferred

Tags: bandwidth, band-pass, data-transfer

I am in school for electrical engineering. I am still in introductory circuits.
I have seen bandwidth used in the context of a Bode plot, which was describing the range of frequencies that a filter could pass before cutoff, and this bandwidth (BW) was a magnitude in hertz.
I have heard bandwidth used colloquially to refer to internet speeds, I.E. Gbps. Today in school the term bandwidth was used to refer to a required data transfer rate in bits/second.

I seriously do not understand why these two concepts are both synonymously called bandwidth. They seem to be entirely different concepts to me.

The BW bit/second example in class gave a signal that was limited to a specific band, we were given the signal rate and bit depth.

I am wondering if anyone can explain to me the relationship between these two concepts (one having the units hertz and the other bit/second). I have attached an image below of one of the two concepts I have attempted to describe. Please ignore the bottom plot and focus only on the first.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

[image: Text]

Comment: They are different things. The use of the word "bandwidth" when really "bitrate" is meant is unfortunate, but it's usually apparent from context since the former refers to an analog domain concept and the latter a digital one.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably something you'll get to in your Communications Systems class (or whatever the equivalent is at your school).  I'll lightly spoil the surprise for you right now and tell you the Shannon Capacity of the channel is C = B log2 (1 + S/N).  Where C = the theoretical maximum capacity in bits per second, B is the bandwidth of your channel in Hz, and S/N is the signal to noise ratio of your channel.

There's lots to learn if you search "Shannon-Hartley Theorem", but do yourself a favor and read the paper that started it all: "A Mathematical Theory of Communication" by Claude Shannon.

Answer (score 1):

**Your plot shows a bandwidth from 0.4Hz to 10 Hz so your effective BW= 9.6 Hz**

**[Shannon-Hartley's Theorem](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Shannon%E2%80%93Hartley_theorem) defines the rules for the max. rate in a given BW.** Keep in mind most of these rules are based on white noise or Gaussian noise and not impulse or AC hum or [SMPS noise](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Switching_noise_jitter).

[Bandwidth](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Bandwidth_(signal_processing)) is measured by the range in half-power frequency points.
[Bit Rate](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Bit_rate) is measured by binary bit transfers per second.

It can be measured as a raw data bitrate but is usually the aggregate rate with overhead including parity or error detection/correction codes.

Simple logic communication uses vastly more bandwidth than the bit rate in order to have good and simple signal integrity for a short distance. But for the long haul, high bandwidth has a high-cost sensitivity so compression methods are used or bandwidth limiting filters must be applied to avoid interference.

There are many forms of baseband communication that can compress bit transitions per word and thus compress the minimum bandwidth required to transfer the type of bit rate modulation.  So they are directly related by some math function but not equal. However, an [Ideal Receiver](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Noise_figure) will have a **[BW](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Bandwidth_(signal_processing))** equal or matched to the channel BW to maximize [SNR](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Signal-to-noise_ratio).

For example  *[Run-Length Limited (RLL)](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Run-length_limited)* coding is common to all HDD's and Ethernet, also many remove dc such as all the versions of [biphase](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Differential_Manchester_encoding). There are times when BW efficiency is a huge cost saving so many types of compression are used to get more Bits per symbol then the called the [baud rate.](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Baud) The more bits per baud, the higher the threshold is for SNR to achieve the same error rate with many phase and amplitude levels usually in binary multiples.

Another method of increasing higher bit rates with compressed BW is to split the aggregate bit rate into many smaller channels than can be more easily equalized by using training pulses to flatten the amplitude and phase response and thus increase the SNR to allow up to 1024 bits per symbol.  This is often essential for ultra high bit rates and long ago was used on any modem > 64 kbaud over twisted pairs.